# How can my MVC listener distiguish between different buttons

Tags: java, model-view-controller, awt

This is my first time trying the MVC design pattern, and I'm trying to figure out how my controller class can tell, when a different button is pressed, and how it can then pass it on to model

```
public void addController(ActionListener controller){
    System.out.println("View      : adding controller");
    btnGo.addActionListener(controller);
    btnBack.addActionListener(controller);
}
```

That is how I send it to the controller:

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
    System.out.println("Controller: acting on Model");
    model.actionGo();
}
```

I have only managed to be able to perform one action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if cases in the listener to differ the buttons etc.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if (e.getSource() == btnGo){
        //perform action when btnGo clicked
    }
    if (e.getSource() == btnBack){
        //perform action when btnBack clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `equals` instead of `==`?

Comment: Is this an efficient and effective way to do it? is this the standard for MVC?

Comment: if you have many checks, then a `switch` might be faster, but otherwise this is a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: @meskobalazs `e.getSource` returns a Object and thus the `==` operator for reference check.

Comment: @MuratK. does it need to be view.btnGo if it's referencing a different class?

Comment: @MuratK. Well if it returns the *same* Object, it will really work, though I definitely wouldn't use `==` on reference types.

Comment: @meskobalazs Fun fact the default implementation of `Object.equals()` falls back to `==`. [See here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Objects.java). But you are right it depends on your needs in the end.

Comment: @IHateJava If by other class, you mean another *object*, and if *btnGo* is a public member of that instance, then yes.

Comment: @meskobalazs well it wont let me just use bntGo without referencing the view class

Comment: Of course it won't. What I meant is that you seem to not understand the difference between a class, and an object.

Comment: I thought btnGo is an object in the class View? I'm very new to this :(

Answer (score 0):

can you give us some additional information in terms of context?
for example I use spring and I can do something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateAcerAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateAcerUser(@ModelAttribute("userModel") UserViewBean bean, @RequestParam(required = false) String submitType, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    if (submitType != null && "extend".equals(submitType))
     {
      // do something on extend
      return "targetPage";
     }
     else {
      //dosomething else on submit
      return "targetPage2";
     }
    }
```

with submittype being associated to these two buttons in an html page..

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submitType" id="saveUser" value="extend">Resend Link</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitType" id="saveUser" value="submit">Submit Decision</button>
```

hence give us some context, it's a webapp, a "desktop" application? what technology you use? ..

worst case scenario you can go with determining method branch based on the "originator" of the call, but really.. that's not something i'm overly a fan of...

Comment: it's a desktop application